# Homebrew Command error: zsh: command not found:$

Tags: macos, homebrew

On the Terminal commandline I tried:

```
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/master/Formula/osgeo-saga-lts.rb
```

But I get this response:

```
zsh: command not found: $
```

I also tried using `brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac` and get a similar response:

```
zsh: command not found: #
```

I am not sure what the difference is from $ or # and why I get these responses.

I have tried using a `export PATH=PATH...` fix of two variants in the homebrew folder, but this isn't working either...

What fix or mods can I make for it to work and download the content for QGIS?

Comment: Did you actually type the $ or is it your shell prompt?

Comment: It is just as you read, I typed the $. 
I used the copied GitHub code from: https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac#readme

They make is sound super simple, just type these lines in with the formula, and you get the content download.

Comment: I tried using this solution: 
cd /opt/homebrew
    nano ~/.zshrc
    export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
I hold control+x for a Y/N prompt to save the pathway. It's supposed to make the command accessible to other directories? It doesn't seem to be working if that is the issue or something is wrong. Would reinstalling brew be the answer?

Comment: Must I modify the user file name to write also when editing the GNU nano? I have been picking the default "/users/..../.zshrc" or do I need to redirect it to where "/opt/homebrew/"
?

Comment: I just tried removing the $ but another error:
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 1 formula.
Error: Non-checksummed download of osgeo-saga-lts formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported! `brew extract` or `brew create` and `brew tap-new` to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.

Comment: I still could use some help, I tried looking for the content to extract or create as it suggests but nothing is there related to the formula on the mac.

Comment: You need to read some Unix tutorials, many of your issues are not knowing how to interact with a shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already learned not to use the # or $ signs in your commands. To install a formula via brew from a link, you need to follow this guide.

1. Install wget: enter `brew install wget` in your terminal
2. Navigate to home directory: `cd` in terminal
3. Download the rb: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/master/Formula/osgeo-saga-lts.rb` in terminal
4. EDIT: this rb is in an old format. As specified in this [guide](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2429), you need to slightly modify the rb (delete the bottle-do section). Download the modified rb [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pi7r4khofo1n40t/osgeo-saga-lts.rb?dl=0). If you dont trust me, then you can follow the guide on github and modify the rb yourself
5. Install rb: `brew install --HEAD -s osgeo-saga-lts.rb` in terminal

Comment: Thank you for the info! I will try it out this afternoon.

I am looking at OSGeoHomebrew website for Mac QGIS, and I got stuck at where the code was depricated (Heading: Install Build and Linked Library Dependencies). 


https://osgeo.github.io/homebrew-osgeo4mac/docs/developing-on-QGIS-using-OSGeo4Mac/

The advise to learn more Unix sounds good. Any recommended places to start?

Comment: My question is, will downloading wget integrate automatically into QGIS like in the steps for the Mac when I download it for SAGA or need I use more of the commands listed on this website? Or must I make it at a specific cd related to my Mac QGIS installation where it may be used?

Comment: In regards to the current answer, I've got through to step 4 now, and I received 
Error: osgeo-saga-lts: Invalid bottle tag symbol

I am looking at some other docs on this, and this error appears involved to fix. 
1) would I fork the project code for osgeo-saga-lts
2) Modify the code to work with the current version of brew? 
 -how might I do that? 

Am I headed the right way to solve this?

Comment: @JS_Drone I have updated my answer with a new rb file and a guide to fix this

Comment: Error: Failed to load cask: osgeo-saga-lts.rb
Cask 'osgeo-saga-lts' is unreadable: wrong constant name #<Class:0x000000013bbdc298>
Warning: Treating osgeo-saga-lts.rb as a formula.
Warning: Use wxwidgets instead of deprecated wxmac
Warning: No available formula with the name "osgeo-hdf4" (dependency of osgeo-saga-lts).
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: I got this error after removing the do command by opening the file in a text editor. I see my script matches yours, and I was able to do this with the wget file as well. The downloads gave me the long error above. What can I do with these errors? Must I find more editing to do to the file or other resources to install it?

Comment: I do not exactly understand what QGIS/Osgeo does, but it has gone out of date over time. It is sufficiently broken so that it will take a large effort to fix (on the developer's part). Have you looked into other options? I see that OsGeo is available for windows via network installer, and that you can download qgis directly for windows and Mac.

Comment: There are some parts of the SAGA model which are being left out of current versions which I need for an important project. Where I am, there isn't windows, all Macs. It sounds like I may need a virtual machine, but I don't know much about that either on a Mac lol. Thanks for your trying! You did great. I didn't think OSGeo is available for Mac, but QGIS has a download. Some of the platforms and the SAGA NextGen is Windows exclusive solution to get all the models I need to use routinely.

Comment: @JS_Drone for a vm, you can try for free here: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-a-free-windows-virtual-machine-on-your-mac-bf7cbc05888e. Leaving windows unactivated is fine, the only thing is that you must use light mode & not change wallpaper. If you want better performance windows VM, consider buying parlells. If your macs are intel, you can also use boot camp to install windows on your mac directly (along with macos): https://support.apple.com/boot-camp

Comment: Have you tried the VM VirtualBox from Oracle? How would you rate that one? 

Will the multi-threading QGIS uses be available on the Mac using the light VM?

Comment: @JS_Drone I have used virtualbox, it is quite slow on my 4-core i5 7th gen with 24 gigs of ram. No harm trying it since it is completely free. A better option (seems like) is UTM: https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/windows-10. Use x86, arm is slow due to emulation vs virtualization.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this issue in M1 chip. So After installing run this:

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it worked but only for that terminal window 
how to set it parmenently ?

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution:

1. Install Homebrew | https://brew.sh/

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Add Homebrew to your path | Read terminal after Homebrew installation

   See below for example, replace [USERNAME]

```
echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/[USERNAME]/.zprofile
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/[USERNAME]/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

3. Try original command again. You won't receive this error message anymore.

```
zsh: command not found: $
```

Comment: how does this solve the problem of trying to run a command called `$`?